# ¿ Como ofrecer distintas calidades de video en mi aplicación?

Tags: angularjs, html5, css, nodejs

Estoy haciendo un sitio de videos , y la cuestión es ofrecerlo en diferentes calidades,es necesario tener copias del mismo video en diferentes calidades?,ya que quiero hacer algo como youtube hace y puede cambiar entre calidades en un video,hay alguna forma de hacerlo desde js?

Comment: Podrias probar implementando un servidor de streaming tienes mayor control sobre el stream al no usar un tercero.

Comment: Hola , nunca he hecho un servidor de streaming , me manejo en mean stack , tendrás urls de interés?

Comment: Puedes revisar esto https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems bajo el titulo de "servers"

Comment: @KevinAB pense que youtube lo convertia con algun programa interno, por ejemplo uno de estos http://blog.hostdime.com.co/5-herramientas-gratuitas-para-convertir-videos-html5/ y cuando lo obtenia recien ofrece los videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es posible, debes emplear ffmpeg, aquí tienes la librería para node.js:

> https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

Para que ffmpeg te manipule los datos de los videos para dar diferentes versiones y bitrates y así como realizar conversiones debes emplear MP4Box:

> https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/

El MP4Box te crearas tu DASH-Stream que es como se conoce esta tecnología (Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP)

Después en el navegador deberas poner la url que te ofrece ffmpeg para la transmission.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo más extenso:

> http ://halcyon.ch/dash-tutorial-1-getting-started-with-dash/

Comment: Gracias por el dato ,lo estaré probando.